# Using Google Fonts - Meteor Cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, meteor, fonts, ratchet

Hi ~ I am working on an iOS application with Meteor as the platform and Cordova and Ratchet as the frameworks. I'm having a hard time getting a Google Font to show up in the application. It shows up when I run it on local host, but not within Xcode's simulator.

I am using @import code within my CSS:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,300);
```

I have also tried putting the actual font files in a resource folder and using @font-face instead, to no avail. I understand that this question has been asked before, but I can't seem to find an answer! Any ideas?

Comment: Have you whitlisten the google url?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to allow access to the Google Font in your [Content Security Policy](http://content-security-policy.com/), which is a meta tag that goes in the head of your HTML.  The Content Security Policy has a clause for "style-src" that lists out where CSS etc is allowed to be loaded from.

Cordova's default Content Security Policy looks like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

This allows CSS from 'self' (local)... to enable from anywhere set:

```
style-src *
```

or if you just want local and google fonts:

```
style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com
```

However, this then would still require the device to be online when you are using the font, so you may want to look at tactics to store it in your application's codebase and load it locally rather than over the network.